# I can't seem to get a DataTemplate to work in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have tried several different ways to get a simple DataTemplate example to work. But, I am not having any luck. The data context for the XAML below is being set in the code-behind. The two code examples included here are wrapped in the  element in my application but, that is the only outside consideration. The first code example works. It displays the data. But, if I put the functionality in a DataTemplate, and then try to use the template, it does not work.

Working Example:

```
    <Canvas Height="100" Width="300">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataSheet.Item.ClassId}" Canvas.Left="10"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataSheet.Item.ClassName}" Canvas.Right="100"></TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
```

Example that DOES NOT work (but, no error is thrown):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ClassId}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ClassName}"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSheet.Item}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FirstTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Any advice as to what I am doing wrong would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ItemSource` should be a collection meanwhile `DataSheet.Item` looks like a single item. 
You should wrap it into collection.

Or you could manually add ListBoxItem.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding DataSheet.Item}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I also had to change the DataTemplate to a ControlTemplate but, everything else stayed the same. Its a start. Now I can build on this and add in the more complex stuff. I suspected that the issue might be Collection versus Item but, I hadn't quite gotten it right. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From the working code you have presented, I am assuming that DataSheet.Item is not IEnumerable.
If it is not IEnumerable binding it to ListBox.ItemsSource doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is an important distinction that I had missed. I suspect everything would have worked if the Item was IEnumerable (I haven't tried it). I will stick with the single object, because that is logically more appropriate in this case. But your comment has made things clearer to me, and I will keep it in mind as I implement other pages/forms. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSheet.Item}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}"/>
```

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx) for more info

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't have an effect. Thanks for your help. I marked the answer above as "The" answer. Thanks again, though.

Comment: You code is effectively identical to his. They both set the ResourceKey property on StaticResourceExtension. Your link says as much at the bottom :-)